# generalizing jQuery scroll method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to generalize a scroll functionality I am using to scroll to different sections on a project. Everything works currently, but I am using a lot of repeated code and I wanted to see if there is any way of making the jQuery methods more dynamic so I could use just one method instead of having fixed methods.

header.php:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">

    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li id="about-scroll"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>  
      <li id="proj-scroll"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>  
      <li id="work-scroll"><a href="#">Work</a><li>
      <li id="abilities-scroll"><a href="#">Abilities</a><li>
      <li id="contact-scroll"><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
include("header.php"); 
?>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
      <h1>Allan Araujo</h1>      
      <p>Interactive Resume</p>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="about">
 <?php include("about.php"); ?>
</section>

<section class="projects">
  <?php include("projects.php"); ?>
</section>

<section class="work">
  <?php include("work.php"); ?>
</section>

<section class="skills">
    <?php include("skills.php"); ?>
</section>

<section class="contact">
  <?php include("contact.php"); ?>
</section>

</div> <!--END MAIN CONTAINER-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Finally, script.js:

```
$('#about-scroll').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.about').offset().top
    }, 2000);
});

$('#proj-scroll').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.projects').offset().top
    }, 2000);
});

$('#contact-scroll').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.contact').offset().top
    }, 2000);
});

$('#work-scroll').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.work').offset().top
    }, 2000);
});

$('#abilities-scroll').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.skills').offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

As you can see, I am using basically the same piece of code 5 times, when I really want to optimize it to only use one function. This code and structure works fine, but I want to optimize is so that I am not using the same piece of code that many times.

Is there a way that I should structure my classes/ID so that I can make this more general. I am relatively new to design/javascript. Currently my structure is a little messy and I think I would have to maybe change my class or id names so that I could use them as passable variables into the method?

Comment: Use common class for them....You can use multiple classes by separating with just a space in your html.

Comment: Wouldn't using a common class just make the navigation move to the same section everytime? How would it distinguish between the different sections if they all have the same class? @BhojendraNepal

Comment: I mean to use common class on click handler not inside its....like `#abilities-scroll` should be replaced with common class...

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify this using two steps.

### Step 1.  Move the common code to a function

```
var scrollHandler = function() {
   $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 2000);
}
$('#about-scroll').click(scrollHandler);
$('#proj-scroll').click(scrollHandler);
$('#contact-scroll').click(scrollHandler);
$('#work-scroll').click(scrollHandler);
$('#abilities-scroll').click(scrollHandler);
```

### Step 2.  Instead of assigning the function to each control one by one, assign based on some attribute

Instead of referring to the controls by name, assign each control a fake style (e.g. "scrollable") and assign with one jquery statement:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li id="about-scroll" class="scrollable"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>  
      <li id="proj-scroll" class="scrollable"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>  
      <li id="work-scroll" class="scrollable"><a href="#">Work</a><li>
      <li id="abilities-scroll" class="scrollable"><a href="#">Abilities</a><li>
      <li id="contact-scroll" class="scrollable"><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.scrollable').click(scrollHandler);
```

Purists may prefer to use a data attribute over a style class.

Comment: So I tried implementing this, but it's not working. How is it retrieving the section classes here? It does not seem to know what section class it is supposed to go to.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

Based on your code I targeted the container-fluid li. Then if any of the list items are clicked I take the id that elements id and assigns it to a variable. I then ran that variable through a switch statement when it matches an area i then assign a class and pass that class to a function that runs the jQuery scroll animation.

```
   $('.container-fluid li').click( function(){
       var getClicked = $(this).attr(id);
       switch (getClicked){
           case 'about-scroll':
               var setlocal = 'about';
               scrollAni(setlocal);
               break;
           case 'proj-scroll':
               var setlocal = 'projects';
               scrollAni(setlocal);
               break;
           case 'work-scroll':
               var setlocal = 'work';
               scrollAni(setlocal);
               break;
           case 'abilities-scroll':
               var setlocal = 'skills';
               scrollAni(setlocal);
               break;
           case 'contact-scroll':
               var setlocal = 'contact';
               scrollAni(setlocal);
               break;
       }
   }
```

This is the function that i set up to perform the jQuery scroll. We are passing in the name of the class using local as the function placeholder.

```
function scrollAni(local){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.'+local+'').offset().top;
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: I would also recommend giving the UL an id so that you can better scope the jQuery selector. (focus it more on the target area) So things don't go all haywire if you add more UL elements in that DIV.